# Agenda Group not working with drools 8.29.FINAL version

Tags: drools

We have java rules service microservice & Using drools 7.X version to process the dynamic rules process. business rules (.xlsx) file using the Agenda-groups which is working fine.

After upgrading to drools 8.29.FINAL. kiesession.getAgenda().setAgendaFocus("1")  is returning null.

NOTE :

Drools 7.49 is giving me list of agenda's
**kieContainer.getKieBase().getKiePackages()**.parallelStream()
.forEach(obj -> obj.getRules().stream().forEach(innerObj -> {
agendaGroups.add(KieRuleMetaData.builder().agendaGroup(((RuleImpl) innerObj).getAgendaGroup())
.ruleName(innerObj.getName()).build());
}));

After upgrading to  8.29.FINAL - it's notworking

Appreciate if any help

As per the documentation, changed only drools version on pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Without some reproducer, it is difficult to support you effectively; next time kindly consider providing a reproducer (on GitHub for example) and share it here or via mailing-list on drools-usage or kogito-development

To me, this snippet returns as expected the agenda-group(s) defined in the rules, using 8.33.0.Final in this little reproducer here: https://github.com/tarilabs/demo20230212-so75416633/blob/main/src/test/java/org/drools/demo/RuleTest.java#L32-L34

```java
kContainer.getKieBase().getKiePackages().stream().forEach(obj -> obj.getRules().stream().forEach(innerObj -> {
    LOG.info("Rules contain this Agenda group: {}", ((RuleImpl) innerObj).getAgendaGroup() );
}));
```

I've used some simplified logging as you didn't provide details of `KieRuleMetaData` in your snippet, but as you can see with rules defining

```
rule "will execute per each Measurement having ID color"
agenda-group "mygroup"
when
...
```

The snippet above correctly prints:

```
2023-02-12 10:51:45,868 [main] INFO  Rules contain this Agenda group: mygroup
```

Then, in the test code, as you can see I'm using the agenda-group I wanted by locating it on the agenda and setting it in-focus: https://github.com/tarilabs/demo20230212-so75416633/blob/main/src/test/java/org/drools/demo/RuleTest.java#L58-L69

```java
session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("mygroup").setFocus();
session.fireAllRules();
```

So to me I cannot reproduce any error in using agenda-groups using latest Drools available at the time of writing.

You mention you are using Spreadsheet (.xlsx) for defining the rules, and the agenda group `"1"` is very suspicious it might be interpreted wrongly as number Vs string.

I hope with my very first snippet above, you are able to re-instate the inspection of all the agenda-groups defined in all rules in all packages, so to verify your agenda-group `"1"` is really present.
If not, suggesting you try by writing in Excel as `"aaa1"` instead of the simple digit for one, so to make sure it is correctly saved in the Excel as a string.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time & tying to help me.  I used your sample snippet, no luck. As I mentioned it is working for 7.49.FINAL not working with 8.33.FINAL.
I have uploaded the code with sample xlsx file at below location. 
https://github.com/phanisankarb/drools

I took time to respond to your message, As I have too many restrictions from office laptiop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove annotation from model

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
```

use constructor in test

```
Model benefitRules = new Model();
```